# headers sent but download doesn't start (force download)

Tags: php, header, download, salesforce

I have a lightbox with a form, when the user sends the form a download should start, this is the code I use:

```
function start_download( $path, $item ) {
    $file = $path.$item;
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    header('"Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="'.$file.'"');
}
```

Unless the fact that is a function is a problem, I think it should work right? well it doesn't. No error whatsoever.

Looking at Chrome's developer tools I can see that the headers are actually set `application/pdf`.

Oh, also, when I add `readfile($file)` it seems to read the file but it returns a strange string (numbers and weird symbols).

I searched over this site but nothing seems to work. I really don't know what else can I do. Ideas?

BTW if I "echo" the `$file` it shows the url correctly, I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: I added the `readfile()` because I saw it some snippet, also, removing the quotes didn't worked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function start_download( $path, $item ) {

    $file = $path.$item;

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $item);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        if (readfile($file) !== FALSE) return TRUE;
    } else {
        die('File does not exist');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this returned file does not exist, so I changed it for `die('File '.$file.' does not exist')`, copy/paste the link and bum, the pdf opens :S that's the right path.

Comment: Where are you pasting the link? PHP cannot find your file, there lies your problem

Comment: Well I fixed it, it was a problem with the server configuration (wp multisite and other things) and about the weird symbols I mentioned before. It was actually the pdf file being displayed by the ajax form I was using... anyway this was the best answer, helped me a lot thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've got wonky quotes, for one

```
header('"Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="'.$file.'"');
       ^^--- why double quoting?
```

They're breaking the header call.

Try:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
```

Note that I've put some spaces in there. They're strictly speaking not necessary, but they do help with legibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
function start_download( $path, $item ) {
  $file = $path.$item;
  header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.basename($file) . '"');
  readfile($file);
}
```

As far as I can see this may work, as long as `$file` is a valid local path name to a pdf file. Make sure, there is *absolutely* no other output!

Comment: `$file`returns the correct path yes. I tried your code and it returns some weird string like this `0000266745 00000 n 0000267098 00000 n 0000267133 00000 n 0000267199 00000 n 0000267315`(followed by a lot of symbols)